# Handle links click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I've a very simple question, but I can't find the correct way to resolve.
I have a phonegap app wich has a login, and I check the results with ajax.
I check the form when the user click:

```
<a href="home.html" data-transition="pop">GO</a>
```

The order of the instructions are:
1- The user clik GO.
2- Check the form inputs.
3- IF they'e corrects, go home.html

I can't do a

```
window.location.replace('index.html');
```

because I lost the data-transition.

Another option could be make a link hidden, and trigger his click when necesary, but I dont like it.

The best way it's when click at Go, do something, and if It's necesary go to his href.

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e){

    // Do what all checks you need to do here
    if(something is wrong)
    {
        // Do stuff here
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop propagation of default event.
        return false;
    }  

});
```

This way the `data-transition` will also work, becaue the default event will be stopped only when the validation fails.

Comment: I wont lost the data-transition="pop"?

Comment: Now `data-transition` wont lost.

Comment: It looks nice, I', going to check and then I comment you.

Comment: It doesnt work at all, because i have to wait the ajax request, so I had to use $.Deferred();, but your answer help me ! thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an onclick function and do preventDefault if the conditions for progressing to the link url aren't fulfilled. Have a look at this question:

[preventDefault inside onclick attribute of a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614438/preventdefault-inside-onclick-attribute-of-a-tag)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ajax, then why dont you return **'true'** or **'false'** value depending upon the validation result that you are performing.

Then in your **'success function' of ajax**, you can check if the result is **'true'** or **'false'**, and if validations are **'true'**, you can use window.location.href method of javascript.