# Don't redirect on button click with css

Tags: html, css

I have a button inside a link, how can I make it so that clicking on the button will not cause a redirect, but clicking outside the button will.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="block">
  <button>Don't redirect on click</button>
</a>
```

Is it possible to do with css only?

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/d4mr7mm6/

Comment: That's invalid markup. Interactive content is not allowed within `a` elements, and `button` is interactive content.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't have to be a button, feel free to change it to a `span` if that helps you solve the issue

Comment: Consider using positioning to have the button *appear* over the link, alternatively, a JS callback that calls `stopPropagation` will prevent the link from being clicked. There are many ways of doing this, although the UX is questionable.

Comment: Trying to solve it without js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide what you are looking for. However, you will need to style the disabled button to accommodate the aesthetics. As said before in a previous post, this is not recommended.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="block">
  <button type="button" disabled>Click Me!</button>
</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4mr7mm6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class inside you'r button with the following attributes :

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="block">
  <button class="no-redirect">Don't redirect on click</button>
</a>

.no-redirect{
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

see : [Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css)

Also, it's illegal to nest interactive element inside an anchor.

Comment: I want it to redirect when clicked on the block, just not the button

Comment: I updated my answer. can you confirm if it's working for you ?

Answer (score -2):

It isn't a good html structure, but if you want to stay with this structure I think this will work:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="block" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
  <button>Don't redirect on click</button>
</a>
```

Similar answers here:

- [preventDefault inside onclick attribute of a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614438/preventdefault-inside-onclick-attribute-of-a-tag)
- [preventDefault() on an <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265478/preventdefault-on-an-a-tag)

Comment: but then the link won't work when clicked outside the button