# HTML form onsubmit="return false;" not working

Tags: javascript, forms, onsubmit

Please have a look at the following snippet https://jsfiddle.net/simbunch/1kvfg7h0/3/

As you can see, the script is using pure JS. As it turns out, `onsubmit="return false"` does not work when the form is selected using pure JS, whereas if I change the submit code to `$('#myform').submit()`, then the `onsubmit` works.

My problem is, I cannot edit the script part (CMS environment). What I want to do is to basically stop the form from submitting. Thanks in advance!

-edit- The issue seems to be related to Firefox. The snippet works as expected in Chrome.

Comment: Found that the problem is related to Firefox. If I run the snippet on Chrome, it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Returning false is a JQuery convention.  It doesn't work in vanilla Javascript.

To achieve a similar effect you need to use the "e" argument that's passed into your event handler, and call either its `stopPropagation` or `preventDefault` methods ... but since there are no arguments at all in an `onsubmit` attribute I wouldn't have thought it was even possible from such an attribute.

However, this answer ([Access event to call preventdefault from custom function originating from onclick attribute of tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614438/access-event-to-call-preventdefault-from-custom-function-originating-from-onclic)) suggests a way to do it.  I haven't personally tried it so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can only execute functions in onsubmit attribute of the form tag also returning false won't do anything. You can use event.preventDefault() here.

try something like this below

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="function (e) { e.preventDefault(); } ">
```

Comment: `return false;` does work, but it turns out the problem is with Firefox. Plug your code into the jsfiddle and try running it on Firefox, it'll not work as well: https://jsfiddle.net/simbunch/1kvfg7h0/10/