# HTML Form onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML5, returning false in a form gives the red line, indicating there is an error, even though I am able to achieve my expected output. Is there any way to fix this line and have a bug free code as it is triggering my OCD.
Also, I am a big beginner with my code so please try to keep it as simple as possible. i do not understand JQUERY at all.

[image: return false here brings a red line. even tried it with the "return <function()> and that also gave red line]

Comment: does hovering over the red line give helpful message? `i do not understand JQUERY at all.` - you're not using it, so, don't worry about that - you could try `onsubmit="return userRegister1()"` and have `userRegister1` function `return false`

Comment: It might just be warning you that if you're doing anything more complicated than calling a single function, you should use an event listener instead of inline JavaScript. But without the detailed explanation of the squiggle, it's hard to know.

Comment: @Bravo perhaps jQuery was mentioned because of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56296637/3196753

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="userRegister1(event)">
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <button type="submit">Click me</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  function userRegister1(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <button type="submit" onclick="
            // you can code javascript code here, this's same how you code in <script>.....</script>
            function userRegister1(){
                console.log('your code in userRegister1 function');
            }
            userRegister1();

            // so you return false that's wrong syntax
            //onsubmit='userRegister1(); return false;'
            // return must be use in function, in this case you can use in function userRegister1()

            // BUT i don't suggest use this way
        ">Click me</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: What even is this!!!!

Comment: describe your answer out of the code if you can, welcome to SO!