# Jquery: Stopping after 1st click

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I am trying to implement edit functionality for a HTML element.

Right now my html-pug code is as below

```
div
    label(for="todo" id="todo" + index class="ind-todo-list") test1

        button(type="submit" id="todo" + index class="btn" onclick="editTodo()" ) Edit
        button(type="submit" id="todo" + index class="btn" onclick="deleteTodo()" ) Delete
```

Jquery is as below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ind-todo-list").on("click" , function(){ 
        var todoid = $(this).attr("id"); 
        var newInput = document.createElement("input");
        newInput.type="text";
        newInput.name="todo";  

        $("#" + todoid).html(newInput);
      });
  });
```

But everytime I am clicking at the `test1` my page reloading again even after `input` field added.

What I am trying to achieve is 
    - when I click at `test1`, I will have input box opened, where I can edit the `test1` and save changes. But I am stuck here.

Thank you.

#### Edit 1

I have added `event.preventDefault()` but still experiencing same same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

                    $(".ind-todo-list").on("click" , function(event){
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                        var todoid = $(this).attr("id"); 
                        console.log("Todoid " + todoid);
                        console.log($("#" + todoid).html());
                        var newInput = document.createElement("input");
                        newInput.type="text";
                        newInput.name="todo";  
                        //newInput.id=todoid;  
                        //$("#" + todoid).html("<input type='text' name='todo' id='"+todoid+"'>");
                        $("#" + todoid).html(newInput);

                    });
```

#### Edit 2 - ID fix

```
div
    label(for="todo" id="todo" + index class="ind-todo-list") #{todo.todo}

        button(type="submit" id="todoedit" + index class="btn" ) Edit
        button(type="submit" id="tododeleteq" + index class="btn" ) Delete
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access event to call preventdefault from custom function originating from onclick attribute of tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614438/access-event-to-call-preventdefault-from-custom-function-originating-from-onclic)

Comment: You'll need to call `e.preventDefault()`, because without that your form submits because that's the default `button` functionality.

Comment: Note that it's invalid HTML to have more than one of the same `id` attribute. IDs must each be unique within a document.

Comment: @Sean, I agree. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ind-todo-list").on("click" , function(e){ 
//add an event to prevent default action on the element       
 e.preventDefault();

      });
  });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.